# Is there software that outputs speech-to-text at the Phonological level?

Tags: speech-recognition, text-to-speech, linguistics, speech, speech-to-text

Is there any software out there capable of taking audio files and outputting phonological (IPA) text?

I understand much of the software out there takes it straight to a language, but is there one that is 'teachable'?

Answer (score 2):

[CMU Sphinx](http://cmusphinx.org/) might be able to do what you want. There are a few different versions, but the one I'm familiar with is Sphinx 3. In the [FAQ](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/sphinxman/FAQ.html#8) it says you can get phone segmentations by making your "words" be individual phones (they're not IPA, though).

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain [SIL](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/computing.html) built something close to this, however, I can't remember what it was called, and I can't find any mention of it on the site.  You might contact them directly.